# Using LocalStorage in Ext JS

Tags: extjs, local-storage

I'm trying to learn how to use localStorage in Ext JS. Here's my model:

```
Ext.define('DEMO.model.UserPreference', {
    ...

    proxy: {

         type: 'localStorage',

         id: 'userpreference'
    }
})
```

Then, for testing purposes, inside the launch function, I do this:

```
var store = Ext.create('Demo.store.UserPreferenceStore');
```

(I have the appropriate store)

But when I run the application, I get this error:

```
http:.../proxy/localStorage.js not found
Failed loading synchronously via XHR: 'proxy/localStorage.js'
```

But in tutorials no localStorage.js file is mentioned.

Could you help me solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: change your proxy type "localStorage" to "localstorage"

Answer (score 0):

change your proxy type "localStorage" to "localstorage". by Naresh Tank